# Use of "unlike" while comparing two things, followed by a comma and "in something else"

Tags: comparisons

I am wondering, which one is correct:

> **Unlike in** *something*, in *something else* it is easy to...
>
> **Unlike** *something*, in *something else* it is easy to...

My instinct tells me both versions could be correct, but I just want to be sure. Plus, I guess the preposition does not matter here, it could be "on", "at" and so on. Does **conjunction** matter though? E.g. could we replace **Unlike** with **While** or any other conjunction used for comparison?

Also, does it matter if we add anything after the phrase?

> **Unlike in** *something*, where *this* acts *this way*, in *something else* it is easy to...
>
> **Unlike** *something*, where *this* acts *this way*, in *something else* it is easy to...

In here, since the parentheses might be pretty long, seems for me it is proper to remind the reader that we are comparing some items. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Use **unlike x** when you compare something directly to **x**.

> Unlike rats, bats have wings.

This means bats are different from rats because bats have wings. Rats and bats are compared directly.

Use **unlike in x** when **x** forms the context of your discussion, and you compare something with an aspect of **x**.

> Unlike in running, you need to time your breathing carefully when swimming.

This means breathing while running and breathing while swimming are managed differently; it does not compare swimming with running directly.

Answer (score 0):

The "unlike" is of no relevance here; what matters is the clause that the *something* is the object of. For example:

> Unlike with biscuits, which get soft as time goes on, in the cake world you will find that hardness indicates something has been sitting around for a long time.

So your example "Unlike something, where this acts this way" is incorrect, as "something where this" doesn't work. It either needs to be "**somewhere** where this" or "**in something** where this".